# AWS RDS Proxy incompatible with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, entity-framework, amazon-rds

I seem to be having an issue with Entity Framework running in my AWS Lambda functions when connecting to an RDS instance, running MySQL 8.0, via RDS Proxy. It seems to be a compatibility issue, whereby when Entity Framework runs a SQL update command I get an error around concurrency - something similar to the stack below:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
  An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MyProject.MyDbContext'.
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithRowsAffectedOnlyAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithRowsAffectedOnlyAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This error indicates that it tried to update a record in my database, but got a "rows affected" count of zero, when in fact the target row was updated, which should result in a "rows affected" count of 1.

To go a little deeper, the query that is being performed is a simple UPDATE statement with a row count call after.

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1;
  UPDATE `myTable` SET `myValue` = @p0
  WHERE `myId` = @p1;
  SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

As mentioned, this SQL command does update the row, but returns 0 which causes Entity Framework to thing a concurrency issue occurred.

This only seems to be an issue when Entity Framework is connecting to my RDS instance via RDS Proxy. When connecting directly to the RDS instance, Entity Framework seems to work as expected and every thing goes smoothly. So I imagine the cause must be an issue with compatibility with RDS Proxy.

For context, I am running an RDS instance using MySQL 8.0, along with the latest version of Entity Framework Core in .NET 6, using Pomelo as the driver.

Any help is appreciated and feel free to ask for more context if needed!

**UPDATE:**

Below is part of the CloudFormation code I'm using to create the RDS Cluster with the RDS Proxy - mostly standard boilderplate.

```yaml
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Snapshot
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones: !Ref AvailabilityZones
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
      DatabaseName: "app-name"
      EnableCloudwatchLogsExports:
        - audit
        - error
        - general
        - slowquery
      Engine: aurora-mysql
      EngineVersion: 8.0
      ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration:
        MinCapacity: !Ref MinCapacity
        MaxCapacity: !Ref MaxCapacity
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBMasterUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Sub "{{resolve:secretsmanager:${DBCredentials}:SecretString:password}}"
      StorageEncrypted: true
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecurityGroupId
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref SubnetGroup

  ProxyAccessRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${Environment}-db-proxy-access"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: 
                - 'rds.amazonaws.com'
            Action: 
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub "${Environment}-db-secrets-access"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'
                Resource: !Ref DBCredentials

  DBProxy:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxy
    Properties:
      Auth:
        - AuthScheme: SECRETS
          IAMAuth: DISABLED
          SecretArn: !Ref DBCredentials
      DBProxyName: !Sub "${Environment}-proxy"
      DebugLogging: false
      EngineFamily: MYSQL
      IdleClientTimeout: 1800
      RequireTLS: true
      RoleArn: !GetAtt ProxyAccessRole.Arn
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref ProxySecurityGroupId
      VpcSubnetIds: !Ref SubnetIds

  DBProxyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup
    Properties:
      DBProxyName: !Ref DBProxy
      DBClusterIdentifiers: 
        - !Ref Cluster
      TargetGroupName: default
      ConnectionPoolConfigurationInfo: 
        MaxConnectionsPercent: 100
        MaxIdleConnectionsPercent: 50
```

**UPDATE:**

For clarity around Entity Framework package versions, I am using the following:

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` | 7.0.8 |
| `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` | 7.0.8 |
| `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` | 7.0.0 |
| `MySqlConnector` | 2.2.6 |

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide your tf  code for the RDS Proxy, as you have identified the issue only occurs with the proxy

Comment: @djmonki, I'm not using TF here, but CloudFormation. I hope this helps!

Comment: What version of Entity Framework Corrle are you you using?

Comment: @djmonki I've made an update to the question with a table of package versions

Comment: Can not see anything wrong with setup, unfortunately I cuurently do not have an environment to test. I think this is definitely an issue and needs to be raised as a bug with AWS against the RDS proxy. The only other thing, that you could try is used the Oracle distribution of MySQL Connector for C# and see if it works directly with the RDS and then whether the same behaviour exhibits with the RDS Proxy. That would add more weight/justification for raising the bug with AWS. Could possibly get it up as a P2.

Comment: Is this somehow related to your issue: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1736

Comment: FYI - MySqlConnector v2.2.7 was released about 5 days ago, worth a try ?

Comment: That issue you've linked, was also an issue I ran into but have solved that by specifying the specific MySql version. I will try upgrading the version of MySqlConnector and see if that helps. If not, I will reach to our AWS contact. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but in your CloudFormation code i see as engine "aurora-mysql".
Aurora is not completely compatible with MySql, you issue is seem a compatibility problem with mysql driver of EntityFramework for Aurora.